# ASP.NET: Forms authentication across applications: matching password encryption settings

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have two websites that both create users in their own separate ASP.NET authentication databases.  Below is the Web.configs for both. I also made the `aspnet_Applications` database records identical on both solutions. When I create a user, the encrypted passwords are not identical, nor are the password salts.

**Any idea how to make two websites create the same password hashes when both systems have the same user name and password?**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <!-- The name, protection, path, validationKey, validation, decryptionKey,
           and decryption attributes must be identical across all applications. 
      -->
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"
             name=".ASPXAUTH" 
             protection="All"  
             path="/" 
             domain="contoso.com" 
             timeout="2880"
             requireSSL="false" 
             cookieless="UseCookies" 
             enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
    </authentication>
    <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
    <!-- The validationKey is not wrapped in the solution -->
    <!-- These keys are examples -->
    <machineKey
         validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D940
                        1E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51
                        F17C529AD3CABE" 
         decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
         validation="SHA1"
         decryption="Auto" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SqlMembershipProvider, which it sounds like you are using, generates a random 128-bit value as the salt. I.e., it includes this value when it hashes the user's password as a security measure. In order to ensure two independent systems produce the same hash, you would need to ensure that the PasswordSalt column value is the same for the same user. There is no property on the MembershipUser for setting the PasswordSalt. That means you either have to go directly to the db to set it, build a custom MembershipUser with this property and the ability to save it or build a custom class or method that provides this ability.

Comment: That did the trick.  If I sync the password databases to last modified, including the password and the salt, authentication works fine.  However, we did notice that it creates collisions on User GUIDs to our amazement even with a short list of samples.